# How do I interpret this Python Code?

Tags: python, list

This is the Code I am looking at https://github.com/Katee/quietnet

In this project, there is a file named quitenet.py

In this file, there it is.

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

I have no idea how I can understand the meaning `l[i:i+n]` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to try it on some data. For example, let's make a list:

```
>>> l = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', ... 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

I shortened the list, but it's all the letters you expect. Now try it:

```
>>> list(chunks(l, 3))
[['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['d', 'e', 'f'],
 ['g', 'h', 'i'],
 ['j', 'k', 'l'],
 ['m', 'n', 'o'],
 ['p', 'q', 'r'],
 ['s', 't', 'u'],
 ['v', 'w', 'x'],
 ['y', 'z']]
```

So what's happening here is that as `i` increments through the loop (skipping `n` elements at a time), the routine yields out the next `n` elements of the original list. This return strategy is called a "generator," and it's signaled by the `yield` statement. Yield is like `return`, but if the routine is called again, it will "keep going from where it last left off."

Another way to exercise this is in a loop:

```
>>> for c in chunks(l, 4):
>>>     print c
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']
['q', 'r', 's', 't']
['u', 'v', 'w', 'x']
['y', 'z']
```

Every time through the loop, `c` becomes the next "chunk" of the original iterable. What's yielded from `chunks` to the loop is a slice of the original list `l[i:i+n]`. In this case, I asked for `n=4` so you can see the difference.

As you learn how to use `enumerate`, `chunks`, and similar generators, you'll find them *enormously* helpful. See e.g. the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

`:` is a slicing operator for lists.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1539655)

> ```
> a[start:end] # items start through end-1
> a[start:]    # items start through the rest of the array
> a[:end]      # items from the beginning through end-1
> a[:]         # a copy of the whole array
> ```

So, there is an example

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5] 
print l[1:3]
>> [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's slicing. So, in that part, it slices the list `l` from `i` to `i+n-1` (includes element in index `i`, until index `i+n-1`, but exclude element in index `i+n`)

Answer (score 0):

`l[i:i+n]` is [slicing syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), and it gets a subsequence from index `i` (inclusive) to index `i+n` (exclusive). Unlike indexing, it never raises exceptions; if the slice goes outside the sequence, the slice is just shorter than you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `l[i:i+n]` returns a slice of array `l`, specifically the elements from `i` to `i+n-1`.  This is a generator expression and each call will return the next `n` elements from the array since the last time it was called.

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of string formatting called `slicing`. It involves sectioning a part of the string using slicing notation, `:`. Here is how it works:

```
[starting_point:ending_point]
>>>l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>>a = l[1:3]
>>>print a
[2,3,4]
```

Once you know this the code becomes easy to read. You are slicing the string from the section `i` to whatever `n` is supposed to be. `n` is also apparently the interval that the range jumps with each iteration.

You can read more on slicing here: https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/slicing.html

Answer (score 0):

The function is a generator that returns incremental slices of `l` that are `n` elements long.

Consider the following:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

a_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14]

for slice in chunks(a_list, 4):
    print(slice)
```

Produces:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13]
[14]
```

Which are non-overlapping slices. The trick to this is that the slice notation extracts elements from the starting index to the (ending index -1).